# MySQLi Dynamic Prepared Statements strange behavior

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have successfully wrote a script that will prepare and bind any parameters to a sql query but I am having trouble on the binding results part.

Here is my script:

```
public function query( $query_string, $params = null, $param_types = null) {

    //prepare the statement
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query_string);

    //check if the sql query is wrong.
    if($stmt === false) {
        echo "Wrong SQL: " . $query_string . "<br />Error: " . $this->db->errno . " " . $this->db->error;
    }

    if($params != null && $param_types != null) {

        //build the array that needs to pass the args to bind_param.
        $a_params = array();
        $a_params[] = &$param_types;

        for($i=0; $i<count($params); $i++)
            $a_params[] = &$params[$i];

        // $stmt->bind_param('s', $param); equivalent
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $a_params);
    }

    //run the query
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $fields = array();
    $out = array();

    $count = 0;

    while($field = $data->fetch_field()) {
        $fields[$count++] = &$out[$field->name];
    }    
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $fields);

    $results = array();
    $k = 0;

    // loop through all result rows
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $results[$k++] = $out;
        print_r($out);
        echo "<br />";
    }

    $stmt->close();

    return $results;
}
```

It seems to bind correctly when I output with print_r, but when I add to an array to return (for use in later script it has odd behavior).

Example call to the method:

```
$users = $TCS->query("SELECT name, age, id FROM test");

foreach($users as $user) {

    echo $user['name'] . ': <br />';
    echo '    age: ' . $user['age'] . '<br />';
    echo '     id: ' . $user['id'] . '<br />';
}
```

But here is my output:

```
Array ( [name] => jake [age] => 18 [id] => 1 ) 
Array ( [name] => ryan [age] => 19 [id] => 2 ) 
Array ( [name] => stephen [age] => 16 [id] => 3 ) 
stephen: 
age: 16
id: 3
stephen: 
age: 16
id: 3
stephen: 
age: 16
id: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Change `$results[$k++] = $out;` to  `$results[$k++] = array_flip(array_flip($out));`

Here is an explanation of what is happening.

```
var_dump($out);
// first iteration
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  &string(4) "mike"
  ["id"]=>
  &int(1)
}
// second interation
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  &string(6) "amanda"
  ["id"]=>
  &int(2)
}
```

The important point to notice here are the ampersands, they mean that the values of `id` and `name` are references. What those references are pointing to will be changed when `$out['id']` and `$out['name']` are. Thus the statement `$results[$k++] = $out;` means copy `$out` and assign it to `$results[$k]`, this includes copying the references. In the next iteration what is being referenced in `$results[$k-1]` is changed to the new values behind your back.

Here is a simple example;

```
$i = 1;
$a = array('id' => &$i);
$b = $a;
$i = 2;
var_dump($a,$b);
// output
array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    &int(2)
}
array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    &int(2)
}
```

### You can fix this by modifying the line:

`$results[$k++] = $out;` to  `$results[$k++] = array_flip(array_flip($out));`

The inner `array_flip` will dereference the values and make them keys, the outer flip reverse the process.

But I would suggest rewriting everything below `$stmt->execute()` as follows.

```
//run the query
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if (!$result) { return array(); }
$ret = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($ret, $row);
}
return $ret;
```

Comment: works flawlessly. and get_result() doesn't work without the driver installed.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, I guess I have always just had the native driver.